# Dynamically adding a View to a LinearLayout with height of wrap_content doesn't display anything

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to dynamically add a view to a `LinearLayout` using the `wrap_content` height. However it doesn't work unless I add a defined `dp` height such as `300dp`. Why can't I programmatically add the View and having the Parent `LinearLayout` wrap the contents?

The view I'm trying to add:

```
public class ImageCanvas extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageCanvas";

    private Bitmap icon;

    public ImageCanvas(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.piggy);
        if(drawable != null){
            icon = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "ImageCanvas: " + icon);
    }

    public ImageCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageCanvas(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

The `LinearLayout` I'm trying to add the above view to:

```
             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawingPad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_create_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:paddingBottom="32dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="32dp"/>
```

Creating the view programmatically and adding it:

```
LinearLayout drawingPad = findViewById(R.id.drawingPad);

ImageCanvas imageCanvas = new ImageCanvas(context);
drawingPad.addView(imageCanvas);
```

It works when I set the XML LinearLayout to a defined height like `200dp` but it doesn't work with `wrap_content`, how can I get it to do so with `wrap_content`?

**_________________________________________________________**

**Update 1:**

I simplified everything down to the XML layout and the issue turned out to be a Parent `NestedScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_create_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:text="Create image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawingPad"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:paddingBottom="32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_create_image" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is the entire layout. When you add a `NestedScrollView` and you try to add a view programmatically, the Bitmap WILL NOT draw on screen. When you remove the `NestedScrollView` the Bitmap will appear. If anyone knows how to do it with a `NestedScrollView` please share!

Comment: What is the "piggy" drawable? Can you post it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PN4kjvc this. why does the drawable matter in this case?

Comment: The drawable may have been something unusual but a jpg is pretty straightforward. You could have a _ConstraintLayout_ issue rather than a drawable issue.  Anyway, I put your code into a blank project and it works OK with wrap content. If you are stumped and don't get a good answer, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @Cheticamp Yeah you're correct. It wasn't an issue with the code. After I simplified everything down to a minimal example, it turned out to be a problem with having a ```NestedScrollView``` as the root layout, which causes the Bitmap to not appear at all (updated the full layout above). Still trying to figure out a solution with a ```NestedScrollView```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide measurements of *ImageCanvas* with an `onMeasure()` override:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(icon.getWidth(),icon.getHeight());
}
```

See [Custom View Components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#extend-ondraw-and-onmeasure).

When you explicitly supply a height, that height is set in the custom component. With wrap content, the height gets set to zero since it is neither specified nor explicitly measured. The above code will provide the correct measurements.

(`icon.getHeight()` is what you really need and corresponds to `wrap_content`. You may need a different value for `icon.getWidth()` depending upon your design.)

Not sure why a *NestedScrollView* has any effect, but the code above will help.

Comment: I tried your answer but it still doesn't seem to display the bitmap. Here's my fullcode https://pastebin.com/xyciUTNe Everything works fine until you add the ```NestedScrollView``` as the rootview. Remove it, and it works fine displaying the bitmap.

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE I am confused by your pastebin code. It doesn't even have a LinearLayout and drawingPad is an ImageView there and not a LinearLayout like in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I had to change it a bit because I couldn't get it to work

Comment: @DIRTYDAVE I understand, but the question doesn't seem to reflect the current circumstances. I also don't see the onMeasure() code in pastebin. On a side note, I would also take out all match_parent dimensions in direct children of ConstraintLayout and replace it with `0dp` with the appropriate constraints. match_parent is really illegal in ConstraintLayout although there is no lint check for it. match_parent can cause odd problems.

Comment: ....I know this is crazy random, but after I added ```android:fillViewport="true"``` to the ```NestedScrollView```, the bitmap loads. I was just about to give up

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lay with your constraint layout.
for constraint layout >= 1.1

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

for constraint layout <1.1

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

This always gets me maybe it got you.
(edit) this needs to be in the child of the constraint layout not the constraint layout itself, ie LinearLayout.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding! I simplified everything down to a very simple layout (update in question above) and it turned out to be an issue with having a ```NestedScrollView``` as the parent. I tried adding your solution to the xml in the constraint layout but that didn't help.